# Can I convert TeamProject into branch in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs

I have TeamProject where developers already started working and created many folders. We realized later that we need MainBranch and FeatureBranch to do some parallel development. Is that okay to convert TeamProject into MainBranch?

MSDN says, converting folder into branch is ok. But they didn't mention about converting TeamProject into branch.

Though TFS2010 allows me to perform the mentioned operation, I'm not sure whether this is good practice or not. Please let me know.

Comment: Can you post the existing folders structure?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you could do that -- and I don't think you can -- I don't see why you would.

Create a new folder in the root of the team project called `Main` and move everything into it via Source Control Explorer. Then you can branch the `Main` folder.

Comment: As I didn't create any branch in the starting of the project, I created project folders under TeamProject. So, I thought of just converting the TeamProject itself into Main branch that is why I asked this question to know am I doing right. Anyhow, to not to disturb the TeamProject hierarchy, I did like what you mentioned. Thanks!